# How to create a testing SQL database file that simulates multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest

My solution to automate integration tests is MSTest with a test database that is checked into source control so that developers can regression test expected results.

The problem is this application has 2 databases that are tightly coupled and reference each other in stored procedures (ie, `SELECT xx FROM [OtherDB].[dbo].[Assets]`). How do you create SQL database files that can reference each other? For example, if I name a second database file as `OtherDB`, will I be able to reference it in stored procedures from the `MainDB`? Or should I just create additional schemas in the `MainDB` to keep database tables separate and easy to identify?

For the record, we have a very poor database schema and our application has a terribly tightly coupled design that limits unit testing capabilities. Mocking has only taken me so far. In addition, most of our business logic is embedded in stored procedures. I'm trying to make the best of this poor design and limited budget/time schedule.

Setup:

- VS 2013
- .NET 4.5
- SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: SQL database file (.mdf) -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx